# Relative Performance loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, quantmod

I'm not a programmer by any means and have been trying to learn R to code various trading strategies.  I'm trying to calculate the relative performance of a list of stocks versus the S&P 500 and save it to a matrix.  It appears that what I've written only goes through the first symbol and then stops.  Below is the code that I've come up with.  I appreciate any help, input and advice on how to proceed.  Thank you.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
symbols <- c('IBM', 'GE', '^GSPC')
getSymbols(symbols, src = "yahoo", from = "2010-12-31", to = Sys.Date())
symadj <- cbind(IBM[,6], GE[,6])
sp5adj <- GSPC[,6]
# Calculate Relative Performance vs S&P and save data
for (i in length(symadj)) {
  rp <- matrix(symadj[,1]/sp5adj, nrow = 1070, ncol = 3)
  print(tail(rp))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_You are not looping over an array but over a single number:

```
for (i in length(symadj))
```

Try (see the seq added, watch the parenthesis. Plus, be careful with length, the iteration is over ncol - i.e. the columns):

```
for (i in seq(1,ncol(rp),1))
```

_Also, you are going always through the same column:

```
  rp <- matrix(symadj[,1]/sp5adj, nrow = 1070, ncol = 3)
```

_A thing I skipped: you should build your matrix before the loop:

```
rp <- matrix(0,nrow=1071,ncol=2)
```

And then assign without overwritting your previous matrix - you have already build it (plus, look at the i where the 1 was, now you are iterating)

```
rp[,i] <- symadj[,i]/sp5adj #This inside the loop
```

_Your for loop should end up looking something like this:

```
rp <- matrix(0,nrow=1071,ncol=2) 
for (i in seq(1,ncol(rp),1)) {
    rp[,i] <- symadj[,i]/sp5adj #This inside the loop
  print(tail(rp))
}
```

\!/ Now there are 1071 days in that period, so the matrix should have one more row - that's why the 1071.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I'm trying to get the loop to run the calculation (IBM/S&P) on each row of data for IBM versus the S&P and when that is complete to run the calculation (GE/S&P) on each row of data for GE versus the S&P. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me with the code, You are correct, it should only be two columns.  I made the changes you suggested and it still only saves one column.  I can see the loop is working, when I use the print(tail(rp)), it shows data for both IBM and GE, however, it still won't save both columns.  I tried using append, but that didn't work either.  Can you think of any other ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: I tried to be more clear and added at the end of the question what the for loop should look like (and the rp declaration before it). If you replace the code below your comment for it, it should work. Maybe it would be clearer if you printed outside the loop, so you do not repeat printing zeros if you build a bigger matrix.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate your help!